# use debsums to automatically check all installed packages

Tags: security, rootkit

I want to use `debsums`to check integrity of all my packages with

```
sudo dpkg -l | awk {'print $2'} | xargs | debsums |grep -v OK
```

But I get those errors:

```
debsums: can't open fwupd file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/fwupd.pkla (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open geoclue-2.0 file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/geoclue-2.0.pkla (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open gnome-initial-setup file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/gnome-initial-setup.pkla (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open linux-image-5.0.0-31-generic file /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-31-generic (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open linux-image-5.0.0-32-generic file /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-32-generic (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open linux-modules-5.0.0-31-generic file /boot/System.map-5.0.0-31-generic (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open linux-modules-5.0.0-32-generic file /boot/System.map-5.0.0-32-generic (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open network-manager file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pkla (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open packagekit file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.packagekit.pkla (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open policykit-desktop-privileges file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla (Permission denied)
debsums: can't open systemd file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/systemd-networkd.pkla (Permission denied)
```

How do I prevent those errors? And why can't even root read those files?

Finally, I would like to create some minimal rootkit detection system that sends out an E-Mail if there is any output

Comment: If your example code is complete it can be simplified to `sudo debsums -s` . The `-s` silences non error results. However if the final code will be use `dpkg` to search for a pattern, would you consider editing you question to clarify the desired function of the finished code snip-it.

Comment: " And why can't even root read those files?" you are not using root to do this. You are using `sudo dpkg -l` to use your admin to do this. All the other commands are not using `sudo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dpkg -l | egrep '^ii' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo debsums | egrep -v 'OK'
```

Comment: Maybe this is the better approach: `debsums -e | grep FAILED`

Comment: this checks only config files.

Comment: dpkg already includes such a check by now: If you want only warnings of modified packages, (not modified config files) use `sudo dpkg -V | grep -v '??5?????? c'`